# How to get and save individual joined values from multiple tables in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I can't get too specific as far as what we're doing, but here goes:

We have Reps that are clients of ours and they can each only work with one Firm, but each Firm has their own way of identifying their reps, however all Reps are stored in our `Rep` table.

The PK in our `Rep` table is `RepID`, however because of their IDs assigned to them by their respective firm, we also have a varchar `RepNumber`.

Enter the table/entity `RepAddress`. The **table** has a FK to `Rep` via `RepID`, however due to legacy systems the **class** `RepAddress` has to have `RepNumber`.

What I'm trying to accomplish is being able to save/update a `RepAddress` by setting the `RepNumber` and getting NHibernate to get/update the `RepID` in the **`RepAddress`** table from the `Rep` table based on `RepNumber`.

Here's my failed attempt at the RepAddress mapping:

```
<class name="RepAddress">
    <id name="AddressID">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="AddressType" column="AddressTypeID" />
    <property name="AttentionLine" />
    <property name="CareOfLine" />
    <property name="AddressLine1" />
    <property name="AddressLine2" />
    <property name="AddressLine3" />
    <property name="City" />
    <property name="ZipCode" />
    <property name="State" column="StateTypeID" />
    <property name="Province" column="ProvinceTypeID" />
    <property name="Country" column="CountryTypeID" />
    <property name="LastModifiedDate" />
    <property name="SessionActivityID" />

    <join table="Rep">
      <key column="RepID"/>
      <property name="RepNumber" />
    </join>
</class>
```

Thanks for any help in advanced! Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RepAddress` class should have a reference to a `Rep` instance (look up `many-to-one` in the docs)

Since `RepNumber` is not the PK, you need a query to get the `Rep` instance. Then you just assign it.

If you had the `RepID`, you'd be able to do the following, which does not need a DB  roundtrip:

```
repAddress.Rep = session.Load<Rep>(repId);
```

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate Cascades:

Entities has associations to other objects, this may be an association to a single item (many-to-one) or an association to a collection (one-to-many, many-to-any).
At any rate, you are able to tell NHibernate to automatically traverse an entity's associations, and act according to the cascade option. For instance, adding an unsaved entity to a collection with save-update cascade will cause it to be saved along with its parent object, without any need for explicit instructions on our side.

Answer (score 0):

I would say: this is pure business logic. Don't try to make NH do this for you.

Usually it is much easier when you make a difference between the data in the UI (DTO's) and the entities in the database. This allows having logic that interprets the data from the UI before it is stored to the database. When you have your entities in the UI, you get lost quickly.